# Handling Session in spring MVC?

Tags: spring

i'm actually new to handling with spring mvc and in particular i have to implement session in spring mvc. Can anybody guide me out of how to handle with session in spring mvc ?

Comment: Session object already present in spring controller

Comment: Read the docs on `@SessionAttributes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the example of controller method level session

```
@Controller
Class YourController{

@RequestMapping(value = "/yourrequest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String yourMethod(Model model,HttpSession session){

   return null;
}


}
```

You can also put session valid to Controller Class.It is just done by adding SessionAttribute.This will be available in all methods in YourController Class

```
@Controller
@SessionAttribute("sessionName")
Class YourController{

@RequestMapping(value = "/yourrequest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String yourMethod(Model model){

   model.addAttribute("sessionName",valueToBeAddedInSession);
   return null;
}

}
```

Here the name of object added in Session should be same as it is added in modelAttribute e.g. sessionName.

The problem in case of session attribute is that we have to invalidate it manually

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
 @Controller 
    @SessionAttributes({ "sessionVar1","sessionVar2" })
    public class StartController {

        public ModelAndView methodName(){
        ModelAndView modelandView = new ModelAndView("view");
        modelandView.addObject("sessionVar1", "sessionVal1");
        modelandView.addObject("sessionVar2", "sessionVal2");
        return modelandView;
        }
    }
```